# How to get python to open an outside file?

Tags: python, file-io, typeerror

I am writing a program for class that opens a file, counts the words, returns the number of words, and closes. I understand how to do everything excpet get the file to open and display the text This is what I have so far:

```
    fname = open("C:\Python32\getty.txt") 
    file = open(fname, 'r')
    data = file.read()
    print(data)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
    TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Python32\\getty.txt' mode='r'
    encoding='cp1252'>
```

The file is saved in the correct place and I have checked spelling, etc.  I am using pycharm to work on this and the file that I am trying to open is in notepad.

Answer (score 15):

You're using `open()` twice, so you've actually already opened the file, and then you attempt to open the already opened file object... change your code to:

```
fname = "C:\\Python32\\getty.txt"
infile = open(fname, 'r')
data = infile.read()
print(data)
```

The `TypeError` is saying that it cannot open type `_io.TextIOWrapper` which is what `open()` returns when opening a file.

---

Edit: You should really be handling files like so:

```
with open(r"C:\Python32\getty.txt", 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    print(data)
```

because when the `with` statement block is finished, it will handle file closing for you, which is very nice.
The `r` before the string will prevent python from interpreting it, leaving it exactly how you formed it.

Comment: Even better would be to use a context manager: `with open(r"C:\Python32\getty.txt") as infile: data = infile.read()`

Comment: @TimPietzcker defiantly, but I felt that was too advanced for this user, no need to add confusion... that said... I'll add it to the answer since it's a really good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in the first line. Should be a simple assignment without the open. i.e. *fname = "c:\Python32\getty.txt*. Also, you'll be better off to escape the backslash (e.g. '\') or put an 'r' for the string literal (this isn't a problem with your specific program, buy may become a problem if you had a special character in your file name). Overall the program should be:

```
fname = r"c:\Python32\getty.txt"
file = open(fname,'r')
data = file.read()
print (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put name part after file like:

```
data = file.name.read()
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting such errors because when you are writing directory of your file you are using a backslash `\` and this is not good. You should use a forward slash `/`. E.g

```
file_ = open("C:/Python32/getty.txt", "r")
read = file_.read()
file_.close()
print read
```

From now on you got all file code under `read`.

file mode ('r', 'U', 'w', 'a', possibly with 'b' or '+' added)

#### Edit:

If you don't want to change the slashes then simply add an `r` before the string: `r"path"`

```
fname = r"C:\Python32\getty.txt"
file_ = open(fname, 'r')
data = file_.read()
print data
```